# Site not rendering on Internet Explorer (Uses Reveal.js library)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, reveal.js

I have just realised that a [site](http://www.troov.co) that I have developed is not displaying at all on Internet Explorer. It's working on other browsers (Chrome and Safari).

I realise that there are ongoing problems with Internet Explorer with some javascript frameworks, but the site won't load any content at all.

I'm a novice, so unsure whether this is a Javascript or a CSS issue. I have read several online guides to trying to get CSS to work with IE, such as [this](http://www.webcredible.com/blog-reports/css/internet-explorer.shtml), but to no avail.

Could anyone please suggest a fix, or an alternative that I could use (perhaps to serve a different site to IE users). Thanks in advance!

Comment: it seems that jekyll build is putting that <div> tag in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site works in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 (Tier 1 browsers, [according to reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/wiki/Browser-Support)). However, you have some invalid code that is causing the site to fall into quirks mode at times:

```
<div><!doctype html>
```

Please remove the `<div>` tag before the doctype; nothing is to precede the doctype.

The site continues to fail in Internet Explorer 9 due to the lack of certain methods and APIs. For instance, Reveal.js expects support for the `classList` API, which wasn't introduced into Internet Explorer [until version 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968262(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you wish to use this tool with IE 9 you will need to [provide a polyfill for `classList`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/index.html#L396).

*If/when you encounter issues like this in the future, open your F12 Developer Tools and look at the console output. In this case, both the `contains` and `add` methods were enumerated. This information would immediately suggest an issue with `classList` to any developer familiar with the API. This will result in a quicker and more reliable answer.*

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks very much for all of the information. Those <div> tags have now been removed, and I'm looking into the providing a polyfill issue.